# I need to use multiple response.redirect in ASP.NET using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-web-developer

I'm writing a school program and I'm trying to move 3 input fields to a new page.

I can get the response.redirect to work on one field but not more.

When I click the button it takes me to the next page and only one field is brought over. Not the 3 that I'm trying to get there.

Can anyone steer my right? Thanks in advance...

Page one:

```
protected void btnEnterSelection_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblBookEntered.Visible = true;
    lblBookType.Visible = true;
    lblPurchaseType.Visible = true;
    lblBookEnteredText.Visible = true;
    lblBookTypeText.Visible = true;
    lblPurchaseTypeText.Visible = true;
    lblBookEntered.Text = "The book you entered is: ";
    lblBookEnteredText.Text = txtBoxBookTitle.Text;
    lblBookType.Text = "The book type is: ";
    lblBookTypeText.Text = drpDownType.Text;
    lblPurchaseType.Text = "The purchase type is: ";
    lblPurchaseTypeText.Text = drpDownPurchase.Text;
}

protected void btnPurchase_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("turtleDoxPurchase.aspx?bookName=" + txtBoxBookTitle.Text);
    Response.Redirect("turtleDoxPurchase.aspx?bookType=" + drpDownType.Text);
    Response.Redirect("turtleDoxPurchase.aspx?purchaseType=" + drpDownPurchase.Text);
}
```

Page two:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblBookEntered.Visible = true;
    lblBookType.Visible = true;
    lblPurchaseType.Visible = true;
    lblBookEnteredText.Visible = true;
    lblBookTypeText.Visible = true;
    lblPurchaseTypeText.Visible = true;
    lblBookEntered.Text = "The book you entered is: ";
    lblBookEnteredText.Text = Request.QueryString["bookName"]; 
    lblBookType.Text = "The book type is: ";
    lblBookTypeText.Text = Request.QueryString["bookType"];
    lblPurchaseType.Text = "The purchase type is: ";
    lblPurchaseTypeText.Text = Request.QueryString["purchaseType"];

    lblCreditCard.Visible = true;
    txtBoxCreditCard.Visible = true;
    lblCreditCardChoice.Visible = true;
    rdoListCreditCard.Visible = true;
    btnSubmitPayment.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: What would that mean? You can only open one page.

Comment: No sir, when I click the button it takes me to the next page and only one field is brought over.

Comment: I don't know if you've ever noticed, but a `Response.Redirect()` usually *ends the response* and nothing else can be sent to the client. An HTTP redirect is sent to the client, and that context is over. This is some of the very basics of how ASP.NET works and is critical knowledge you need to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, you are trying to send three values from Page One to Page Two. In that case, you could build a Query string using the values from txtBoxBookTitle, drpDownType and DrpDownPurchase. The string should be in the follwing format:

```
string queryString = "?bookName={txtBoxBookTitle}&bookType={drpDownType.Value}&purchaseType={DrpDownPurchase.Value}"
```

Then you could append the above string to your

```
Response.Redirect("turtleDoxPurchase.aspx" + queryString);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: You should Server.UrlEncode parameters when passing them (and UrlDecode when processing them in your second page)